# Monitor what a thread is executing with Android Studio 3+

Tags: android, android-studio

I used to have the ability to monitor stack trace of a thread using Android monitor tools in older Android Studio, after updating android studio i cant find how to do that anymore.

going to Debug -> Debugger -> Threads show me threads and their status, there is also overhead and variables views but i cant find where i can see what the thread is actually executing like i could in the older android studio...

How can we view Thread execution stack trace like it was possible before?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According  to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor) DDMS is deprecated from android 3.1 and removed from android 3.2, and there is no an all in one substitute of DDMS in newest android studio versions.

What you can do is enable debugging in your application code (Add following code in `build.gradle`):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and attach your debugger at the running process like explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html).